# NativeScript get current android context with Vue?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to use a native mapping library that needs the context to instantiate the UI object, how do I pass it?

The native function is a extension of android.view.View and the parameters it needs is a Context.

Ref : https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/mapping/view/MapView.html#MapView(android.content.Context)

Example.vue :

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <StackLayout>
            <Placeholder @creatingView="creatingView"/>
         </StackLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            creatingView(args){
                //This is where I need the context as a parameter
                const nativeView = new com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView(this.context);
                args.view = nativeView;                    
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of what flavour / framework you use, you may get the application context using,

```
import * as application from "application";

const context = application.android.context;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current android context from creatingView event args.

```
methods: {
       creatingView(args){
           const nativeView = new com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView(args.context);
           args.view = nativeView;                    
       }
}
```